# How do I send webform submission data to a google sheet?

Tags: 8, webforms

I have implemented the webform module on my Drupal 8.4 site. I have some forms that I would like to submit the data to a google spreadsheet, instead of the drupal database.

Can someone help me get started with this? 
Do I need to create a custom module to implement this functionality? What hooks do I need to use? Is there any documentation/tutorials out there on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the only available solution is to use Zapier.

Ivan Zugec did a great screencast showing [How to Create Forms using Webform and Contact in Drupal 8](https://www.webwash.net/how-to-create-forms-using-webform-contact-drupal-8/) and includes a demo showing how to push webform submissions into a Google Sheet using Zapier.

Hopefully, someone will port the [Webform to Google Docs module](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_to_gdocs) from D7 to D8.

Comment: Thank you! I will follow any progress on the module and use Zapier in the interm.

Answer (score 0):

Zapier only allows a few 100 submissions per month on the free plan. Not worth it for us.

I’ve started using the google script editor to send webform data as a GET request through the webform remote post feature. Unlimited requests and offers better customization, at no cost.
I used [How to Submit an HTML Form to Google Sheets…without Google Forms](https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-submit-an-html-form-to-google-sheets-without-google-forms-b833952cc175) to implement the feature.

Answer (score 0):

i have a better way and did myself.

Create google web form using google apps script and their provided code interface.

and then embed this form into any webpage or can also be used independently.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Zapier, theres a contrib module which do this.
[Webform GoogleSheets](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_googlesheets)